# Upload profile picture in registration process - FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a problem in the registration process when using `FOSUserBundle`. Instead of the real path of the image I'm trying to upload, in the database, it always  saves `initial` value under the `path` column and the image is not uploaded in the directory I have defined.

```
namespace Session\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\SecureRandom;


/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="User")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Session\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
       /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $path;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    public $file;

    /*     * *************************************************************** */



    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if ($this->file == $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($this->file);
        }
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir() . '/' .
            $this->id . '/' . $this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->id;
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        return 'uploads/users';
    }

    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
       return $this->path;
    }


    /**
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     * @return object
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->upload();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the file used for profile picture uploads
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {

        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
            // a file was uploaded
            // generate a unique filename
            $filename = $this->generateRandomProfilePictureFilename();
            $this->setPath($filename . '.' . $this->getFile()->guessExtension());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates a 32 char long random filename
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function generateRandomProfilePictureFilename()
    {
        $count = 0;
        do {
            $generator = new SecureRandom();
            $random = $generator->nextBytes(16);
            $randomString = bin2hex($random);
            $count++;
        } while (file_exists($this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $randomString . '.' . $this->getFile()->guessExtension()) && $count < 50);

        return $randomString;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }
        $this->getFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->getPath());

        if (isset($this->tempPath) && file_exists($this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->tempPath)) {
            unlink($this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->tempPath);
            $this->tempPath = null;
        }
        $this->file = null;
    }

}
```

Database row preview:

[image]

What is the problem?